# How to add a custom error to a template-driven form after changing the two-way binding model?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, two-way-binding, custom-error-handling

In my Angular application I have a template-driven form with two-way binded input fields. If the submission fails, I want to display an error with a generic message. After the submission has finished and failed, the first thing I do is change the model used in the form. Then, I add an error to the form control.

After this, the form is updated with the new model values. But also, the error has been removed. So I guess it has been validated again at that point.

**Below an edited simplified variant of the situation:**

**HTML Form**

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index">
      <span>{{ vehicle.name }}</span>
      <mat-form-field>
       <input
        name="odoInputVehicle{{ vehicle.id }}"
        required
        type="number"
        matInput
        min="0"
        [(ngModel)]="vehicle.distance"
        [disabled]="vehicle.submittable === false"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</form>
<mat-error *ngIf="this.form.control.hasError('submissionFailed')">
  <div>Error submitting the value(s).</div>
</mat-error>
```

**Typescript code**

```
@ViewChild('form', { static: false }) form: NgForm;

performRequests() {
  forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
    results => {
        // Result handling
    },
    error => {
        // Does something with the results

        // One or more requests failed
        // Model change
        succesResults.forEach(result => {
           this.vehicles[result.vehicleId].submittable = false;
        });

        // Apply an error to the form
        this.form.control.setErrors({
          submissionFailed: true
        });
    }
  );
 }
```

How can I add an error to the form that keeps being attached to the form after it also has changed the model. Is there an event to listen to that is fired once the model is updated that I can use for this?

Comment: instead of description, provide not working code

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
<span *ngIf=" this.form.control.errors" class="someClassREDTEXT">Form has error</span>
```

you check if there is an error with this.form.control.error and show the error message

Comment: Wow, this actually works! How is it possible that this works while `this.form.control.hasError('submissionError')` does not?

Comment: If you want personalize error you can do this this.form.control.errors['submissionFailed'] in your ngid i think migth work! try it

Comment: It does not work because `this.form.control.errors` is null. Even when I initialize the `errors` with the error set to `false` in the `OnInit` function.

Comment: if the form submissions fails, print your this.form.controls.errors and if you read "submissionFailed" it mean that the custom error is added.

Comment: It is possible to use `*ngIf="this.form.control.errors && this.form.control.errors['submissionFailed']"` to check for the explicit error.

Comment: try this: this.form.control.errors && this.form.control.errors.submissionFailed

Comment: Unfortunatelly this actually does not work. I tested submissions where the model was not change afterwards. When it does change, the form errors are not coming through.

Answer (score 1):

Like this in ts file

```
this.quizForm.form.controls.email.setErrors({ unique: true });
```

And for Html

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [ngClass]="{
                inputWrong:
                  (quizForm.submitted ||
                    quizForm.controls['email']?.touched) &&
                  quizForm.controls['email'].invalid
              }"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              pattern="[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$"
              [email]="true"
              [readonly]="isLoggedIn"
              [(ngModel)]="email"
              required
            />
            <span
              class="error_span"
              *ngIf="quizForm.controls['email']?.errors?.unique"
              >Email is already registered.</span
            >
          </div>
```